# ajax sending many requests instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code ends up sending too many requests for each click. I viewed my Chrome's network tab. How can I fix it? I am not sure why.
I have basically a ajax call that invokes a REST API that gives me list of all names and I have another REST API that matches that.

For example,

```
/list gives me: list1,list2,list3
```

and

```
/api/list1.json gives me: json of list1..
```

But I have my code where I loop through all the lists and invoke /api/list1.json

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json'
    url: '/lists',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var html = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.apis, function (i, item) {
                html += '<li class="res">';
                html += '<div class="hed"><h2><a class="id" href="/api/' + item + '.json">' + item + '</a></h2></div><div class="slidedown"></div>';
                html += '</li>';
            });
            html += '</ul>';
            $('#exDiv').empty().append(html);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});

$(document).on('click','.id', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = this.href; 

   //function that displays the .json on the browser
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that would send multiple AJAX requests. I suspect the problem is somewhere else. BTW, `$(this).next('.slidedown')` won't select anything. The `.slidedown` DIV is not right after `.id`, it's after the `.hed` DIV that contains `.id`.

Comment: So it should be `$(this).closest('.hed').next('.slidedown').slideto()`

Comment: ok I have even removed that code but problem is that it still throws lot of requests

Comment: What requests is it sending? `/lists` or `/api/listX.json`?

Comment: Could you be calling `$(document).on('click', '.id', ...)` inside a loop?

Comment: its first sending /lists in ajax call and then inside the .each loop if you click on a link then /api/<item>.json request get sent but I notice  for /api/<item>.json there are many requests sent

Comment: Why does clicking send anything? The click handler doesn't send an AJAX request. Did you leave that out of the question?

Comment: @Barmar edited my question

Comment: There's nothing in the question that would cause multiple requests. Like I said before, the only way this would happen is if you call `.on()` multiple times. A common error is to call `.on()` inside the handler for some other event, so every time that event happens, you add another click handler to the same elements.

Comment: Another possibliity is if you have nested elements with `class="id"`. As the event bubbles out from the `<a>`, the handler fires for each of the containing elements with that class.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup instead click event. Click is still sending event while you are pressing the button.

Comment: if I change to keyup, e.preventDefault does not work